# What do you call models that are not invariant to predictor order?

Tags: terminology, conv-neural-network, gaussian-process

Most models are invariant to predictor order, i.e. they do not assume `feature[31]` to be related to `feature[32]` more than to `feature[42]`.

On the other hand, Gaussian Process Regression or Convolutional Neural Networks do assume that the closer two features are, the more likely it is that they are related.

What do you call the property that distinguishes these two kinds of models?

A good candidate may be **permutation invariance**. It is not clear, however, whether this refers to the permutation of the observations or the predictors.

Perhaps a proper name would be **[symmetric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricFunction.html)/asymmetric** model?

Comment: It sounds like what you might have in mind is [exchangeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables).

Comment: @whuber I can't quite see the connection. From the article in your link it seems that a set of variables has the property of being exchangeable. I'm looking for a word to distinguish predictive models that fit a spectroscopic dataset equally well when we randomly shuffle its columns and models that don't.

Comment: Do you have some concrete examples?  I would tend to call such models you refer to as **badly defined**!